# Creating Email Group in Gmail

Tags: networking

I don't know that whether it is the appropriate place to ask this question, so apologies in advances.
We have in our organization an email address like "faculty@xyz.edu" so, whenever anyone sends an email to his email address, it gets forwarded to all faculty members and everyone receives this email in his personal inbox.
I want to create similar email in Gmail so that when I send an email to this 'gmail address', it can forward my email to all the members. How can I do this.
Regards

Comment: G Suite Gmail, or standard Gmail?

Comment: standard Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the G-Suite you can create groups in the admin panel which acts like a mailing list. A member of a group can also be an external email address.

With the regular GMail you could create forwarding rules to other email addresses. You can find a tutorial on how to set-up such forwarding rules [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-auto-forward-emails-to-multiple-addresses-in-gmail/).

Comment: I was checking forwarding in Gmail, but it allows email forwarding to only one email address.

Comment: This is one limitation of Gmail's forwarding functionality. You have to create the forwarding rule for each email address again.